# Azure Cosmosdb (Documentdb) default indexing policy does not work with StartsWith() function

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cosmosdb

I came across the following exception when running the query

```
SELECT TOP 10 c.name
FROM Customer c
WHERE STARTSWITH(c.name, 'Bob')
```

exception:

```
An invalid query has been specified with filters against path(s) that are not range-indexed. Consider adding allow scan header in the request.
```

I fixed the issue by changing the index to

```
{
    "path": "/",
    "indexes": [
        {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "Number",
            "precision": -1
        },
        {
            "kind": "Hash",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": 3
        }
    ]
},
{
    "path": "/name/?",
    "indexes": [
        {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": -1
        }
    ]
}
```

But I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't the default indexing work? Shouldn't `"path": "/*"` index everything?
2. Why is it mandatory to add `"path": "/"`? Why do you need it?

P.S. I have read the index policy section on the [how-to guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies) but still don't quit understand it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why doesn't the default indexing work? Shouldn't "path": "/*" indexes everything?

It does, but what's important is HOW.

The default index did not work because for data type `String` it was created as `hash` index. Hash means that the index is not storing the actual values, but a usually smaller scrambled (hash) values produced by some [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). To get a match you need to compare against a value which produces the same hash. Assuming high-quality hash function of reasonable length, it would require the same original value. So `c.name = "Bob"` would have been covered by that index.

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies) also confirms that by saying:

> Index kind
>   Hash supports efficient **equality** and JOIN queries.

Your query predicate `STARTSWITH(c.name, 'Bob')` was performing a function check against the `c.name` property. `Startswith()` has no good way to produce all possible matching hash values for comparison without scanning all the documents.
So, as the error states: the index you have on given property cannot serve this query.

### Why is it mandatory to add "path": "/"? Why do you need it?

I'm not sure on if/why it is technically mandatory (compared to applying some implicit defaults), but I consider it's a reasonable requirement to make users explicitly stare at the defaults and approve or modify them.

**Design for scale - never do full scan.**
Relational SQL database which is designed for working with sets, DocumentDB, on the other hand, is for schemaless unstructured data, optimized for working *by individual documents* and designed for scale. You should never do a full scan and read all documents as it would not scale. Hence you should design and plan how your data is queried.

**Defaults are almost never optimal.**
As you experienced, each index has different goals - range indexes support sorting but hash indexes are more compact and faster to use. Also suitable index precision depends on your data, value distribution and application needs.

**Cost impact.**
Also, each index is having a cost in storage and additional effort (RU) on each insert/update/delete to keep it in sync. So your indexing choices affect performance and your bill. You probably care about both.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it a bit longer, I think I might have figured out the answer to my questions.

The reason why the default `"path": "/*"` doesn't work is because the dataType for the range index was set to Number and the values for `name` is obviously string. That's why I need to add an additional range index for `name`.

I also noticed that `"path": "/*"` and `"path": "/"` yields the same results. I guess they are interchangeable.